# jQuery Fade Slider - remove defined height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design

I am implementing a jQuery Fade Slider on a site that I am building, although having a defined height is giving me some issues.

I am using columns defined in percentages for their respective width, col-25 = 25% of the width. My images are placed within a class called .img-holder where the width is set to 100%. As of right now, when using the fade slider, the image height is fine at width and height on my screen but when scaling down into smaller screens the defined height obviously becomes problematic as I have left/right arrow navigation over my images and paragraph text below. I didn't want to use a different defined height for each screen variation through @media queries in my css. Is there a way to use the slider without having to define a height for it?

My CSS currently looks like this:

```
.img-holder { background: #EEE; overflow:auto; position:relative; width:100%}
.col { float:left }
.col .img-holder { width:100%; height:auto; margin-bottom:14px; margin-top:5px }

.fades-demo { position:relative; width:100%; height: 100% !important; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; -webkit-transition: 0.5s; -moz-transition: 0.5s; -ms-transition: 0.5s; -o-transition: 0.5s; transition: 0.5s; }
```

My markup:

```
<div class="col col-50">
<div class="img-holder">
    <div class="mgtb fades-demo hide" id="fades1">

        <div>
        <img src="/001.jpg" width="" height="" alt="" class="" />
        </div>

        <div>
        <img src="/002.jpg" width="" height="" alt="" class="" />
        </div>

        <div>
        <img src="/003.jpg" width="" height="" alt="" class="" />
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
<script>
//scripts
$(document).ready(function() {


//initUI
initUI()

//init slider 1
var defaults = {
    speed: 800
    ,timer: 4000
    ,autoSlider: false
    ,hasNav: true
    ,pauseOnHover: true
    ,navLeftTxt: ''
    ,navRightTxt: ''
    ,zIndex:20
}
,as = $('#fades1').fadeSlider(defaults)
,count = 2

//destroy
$('#o-btn-des').click(function() {
    as.destroy()
})

//resize wrapper
$('#o-btn-cs').click(function() {
    $('#fades1').css({
        position:'fixed'
        ,left:0
        ,top:0
        ,width:'100%'
        ,height:'100%'
        ,'z-index': 300
    })
    as.defs.speed = 1000
})

//resize wrapper
$('#o-btn-ns').click(function() {
    var t = '<div class="fades-demo mgtb" id="fades' + ++count +'">' +
    ($('#fades1 .fade-slides').length?$('#fades1 .fade-slides').html():$('#fades1').html()) +
    '</div>'
    $('#wrapper').append(t)
    $('#fades' + count).fadeSlider(defaults)
})
})

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would think that:

```
.fades-demo { height: auto !important; }
.fades-demo img { max-width: 100%; width: 100%; height: auto; }
```

would work just fine.  Of course, this assumes that the slider you are using doesn't remove all the images from the normal flow via float/positioning, which would cause the container to collapse in on itself.  There are a number of solutions to that if the aspect ratio of the images is constant and you know it before hand.  Or hiding an image in the container that is visible:hidden just to keep the right aspect ratio is another solution.  Without knowing which fader/slider you are using, it'd be difficult to help you much further.  Try setting up a jsFiddle if the above doesn't work.

Comment: The auto height doesn't work, and I could be wrong about why, but I think it has to do with it being inside a .col class which is a floating element.

Comment: Shouldn't matter that it is floating, but the slider you are using is likely taking the images out of the normal html flow, likely positioning them on top of each other.  If all else fails, you could always try switching your slider to one that is already responsive like this one: http://flexslider.woothemes.com/

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I was actually using the slider found at [html5beta](http://html5beta.com/jquery-2/jquery-fade-slider/). I'll look into the flexslider as well. I hadn't come across that one before. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Albeit the answer seems to be too late. Someone else facing this issue might want to give a try to the jquery-fade-slider plugin that I created.

The documentation can be accessed at http://jqueryfadeslider.com and the demos can be seen at http://jqueryfadeslider.com/demo